# about MPMoviePlayer Control Style

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

Which style of MPMovie control has DONE button?

I wanna get out of movie on playing.

MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded has no [Done button].

I have to make a custom control bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen` if you need a Done button:

From the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMovieControlStyle):

> MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen
>
> Controls for fullscreen playback are displayed. The controls include a
>   start/pause button, a scrubber bar, forward and reverse seeking
>   buttons, a button for toggling between fullscreen and embedded display
>   modes, a button for toggling the aspect fill mode, and a Done button.
>   Tapping the done button pauses the video and exits fullscreen mode.

Comment: Thanks, jonkroll. I have another problem. On second playing the movie, I can't see control bar after lots of tapping the movie. what can I do?

Comment: Hi @jonkroll   Do u have any idea with below question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942178/ios-mpmovieplayer-contrler-style-issue