# iOS MPMovieplayer controller style issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, seekbar

I have create a VideoPlayer/VideoEditor, I can select a video from device memory by using picker view controller.

The below image shows how seek bar show when play a video but before choose,

**It's show a seek bar with correspondent image**

[image]

After Choose a picture i have use with the selected url to MPMoviePlayerController,

```
   player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]];
  
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
```

[image]

**But show seek bar shows like a common one**,

i want a seek bar with correspondent image like a above one. not a below one.

is it possible, and **any Library available** to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi please some body response with atleast a suggestion.